# What is the law on digital download refunds

Tags: online-payment, refund, online

I was after some advice if possible.

I currently sell digital products online through a 3rd party. The way it works is, i design / develop some code and upload it. The 3rd party prices it accordingly and then list on their market place.

Just recently i had an issue where a customer was not happy with what they had purchased, and requested support. I then liaised with the customer, who never got back to me.

The 3rd party emailed (Thursday) me saying they had received a refund request from the customer. Unfortunately i was away on holiday, and didn't pick up their email until the following Tuesday, i replied straight away.

The next email i received basically stated the refund had been issued, as i did not reply within 2 business days.

I'm not sure what i can / can't do, but it's pretty frustrating and find it extremely ridiculous that i had to reply within 2 business days.

Can i take this further? The 3rd party seem very disinterested.

Also please forgive me if this isnt the right forum.

Comment: What is the law *where*? What does your contract/terms of service with the 3rd party say? That's likely where you will find your answer

Comment: The third party's terms of use policy is most certainly within the law and probably more strict.

Comment: It could depend on the nature of the "market place", but from a _consumer's_ point-of-view, expecting a "business" to respond (even if it's just an acknowledgement) within two working days doesn't sound too unreasonable... the fact that you might be a one-man-band, with no-one to cover probably isn't their concern.

Comment: Would an out of office reply class as an acknowledgement? I have read through the terms of use, and nowhere does it mention about 2 business days to reply.

Comment: @yoozer8 the T&C's are pretty vague to be honest, and doesn't cover any of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You sell on a third party site which will outline the terms of use on their platform. For your interests, their terms of use and policies are effectively the law.

Actual legal concerns on your end would be limited to the legalities of your product alone.

You can always reach out to third party venues to see if their support will meet you somewhere in the middle, but I wouldn't count on it. I sell on third party venues all the time and in doing so I basically agree to the often cruel and unfair rule of "the customer is always right" and in this case, you are not the customer.

To summarize, the answers would be within the terms of use on the third party venue. But generally speaking, you may have to eat it on this one. You were away. That's not the problem of the buyer or the venue. That's planning on your end, and unfortunately, your liability.